# analytic continuation argument

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory, differential-operators

In ["Pseudo-spectra, the harmonic oscillator and
complex resonances"](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/455/1982/585)  (login required), the author says

> Sections $2$ and $3$ of this paper concern the operator $Hf(x)=(-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+cx^{2})f(x)$ acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ where $c$ is a complex constant satisfying $Re(c) > 0$ and $Im(c) > 0$
>
> This operator has a closed sectorial form with form domain independent of $c$, and the resolvent operators $(H-zI)^{-1}$ are compact for all $z$ not in the spectrum spec$(H)$ of $H$ (Kato 1966). Since the eigenvalues of $H$ may be written down in closed form for positive real $c$, **an analytic continuation argument** proves that the spectrum of $H$  must be $\{ c^{\frac{1}{2}}(2n-1):n=1,2,\dots  \}$.

Who can explain the sentence in bold? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but if we have  the following case  :                             Let $T_{a}, a\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ be an unbounded operator defined on  $D$ subspace of $ L^{2}(R)$ such that for  $a\in\mathbb{R^{*}}$ we have  $T_{a}$ is selfadjoint  and its spectrum is $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

For $a\in\mathbb{C^{*}}$ with $Re(a)\not =0$ its point spectrum  is $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Can we say the spectrum of  $T_{a}$ is  $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $a\in\mathbb{C^{*}}$?

Comment: I'd suggest two edits - (1) That you refer us to the paper from which this statement is given. (2) That the editional details you've just written be edited into the original post. Good luck!

Comment: ok,  here it is   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj__NW-tuPMAhVNnRQKHV7vDlMQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frspa.royalsocietypublishing.org%2Fcontent%2Froyprsa%2F455%2F1982%2F585.full.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGa4rRG-GV63TIAZAfQ7trzFHbgnA

Comment: here is the name of the article: Pseudo-spectra, the harmonic oscillator and complex resonances, the author is EB Davies

Answer (score 2):

That closed form is $c^{1/2} (2n-1)$ when $c$ is a positive real.   These eigenvalues must be analytic as functions of $c$ as long as they don't collide or go off to $\infty$, and they don't as long as $c$ stays in the right half plane.  So for any $c$ in the right half plane, the eigenvalues are the unique analytic continuations of $c^{1/2} (2n-1)$ to that half plane, namely $c^{1/2} (2n-1)$ (using the principal branch of the square root).

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but if we have  the following case  :                             Let $T_{a}, a\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ be an unbounded operator defined on  $D$ subspace of $ L^{2}(R)$ such that for  $a\in\mathbb{R^{*}}$ we have  $T_{a}$ is selfadjoint  and its spectrum is $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

For $a\in\mathbb{C^{*}}$ with $Re(a)>0$ its point spectrum  is $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Can we say the spectrum of  $T_{a}$ is  $\{a(2k+1),k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $a\in\mathbb{C^{*}}$?